# Exporting command results into a file (.csv)

Tags: php, laravel, file, export

After running my command in the CLI I want to save the results in a file on my machine. I saw a couple of solutions and all of them require this -
`composer require maatwebsite/excel`
But upon running the command I am given this error...

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.25] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.26, ..., 3.1.35] require illuminate/support 5.8.*|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.25.2] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.41, ..., 3.1.x-dev] require psr/simple-cache ^1.0|^2.0 -> found psr/simple-cache[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 3.0.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.36, ..., 3.1.40] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.18 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.25.2].
    - Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel ^3.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-gd` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require maatwebsite/excel:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require maatwebsite/excel:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Any other suggestions on how to export the files?
`php artisan select:values --year=2020 --month=02` that's how I am running my command

Comment: `[...] php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.2) [...]` ... i think you have to install php 7 or ignore the platform req.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running this solved my problem

`composer require psr/simple-cache:^1.0 maatwebsite/excel:3.1.44 --ignore-platform-req=ext-gd --ignore-platform-req=ext-zip`

Answer (score 0):

- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.25.2] require ext-gd *

By looking at the commandline error you need to enable this extention in your xampp or apache server configurations.

In case of Windows
just enable it in php.ini file like this

[image]

Now find extention:gd2

and remove the semi colon from start like this.

[image]

now simply restart the server and you are good to go.

Comment: Not using Xampp, just solved the problem. Thanks, anyway!